# Can't run multiple execSync commands in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell

I'm trying to run multiple execSync commands in Node, but they don't appear to be working.

My code:

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

execSync('NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --colors --watch', {stdio:[0,1,2]});
execSync('ls -la', {stdio:[0,1,2]});
```

In my terminal, I see the output of the first execSync, but I do not see the output of the second. Any idea why this is?

Comment: how about this execSync('NODE_ENV="development webpack --progress --colors --watch"', {stdio:[0,1,2]});

Comment: Judging by the `--watch` flag, I bet the first command won't end unless you (or other process) kill it.